# Finally closing stream using Scala exception catching

Tags: scala, exception, io

Anybody know a solution to this problem ? I rewrote try catch finally construct to a functional way of doing things, but I can't close the stream now :-)

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._
def gunzip() = {
  logger.info(s"Gunziping file ${f.getAbsolutePath}")
  catching(classOf[IOException], classOf[FileNotFoundException]).
    andFinally(println("how can I close the stream ?")).
    either ({
        val is = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(f))
        Stream.continually(is.read()).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
      }) match {
          case Left(e) =>
            val msg = s"IO error reading file ${f.getAbsolutePath} ! on host ${Setup.smtpHost}"
            logger.error(msg, e)
            MailClient.send(msg, msg)
            new Array[Byte](0)
          case Right(v) => v
        }
  }
```

I rewrote it based on Senia's solution like this :

```
def gunzip() = {
  logger.info(s"Gunziping file ${file.getAbsolutePath}")

  def closeAfterReading(c: InputStream)(f: InputStream => Array[Byte]) = {
    catching(classOf[IOException], classOf[FileNotFoundException])
      .andFinally(c.close())
      .either(f(c)) match {
      case Left(e) => {
        val msg = s"IO error reading file ${file.getAbsolutePath} ! on host ${Setup.smtpHost}"
        logger.error(msg, e)
        new Array[Byte](0)
      }
      case Right(v) => v
    }
  }

  closeAfterReading(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) { is =>
    Stream.continually(is.read()).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer this construction for such cases:

```
def withCloseable[T <: Closeable, R](t: T)(f: T => R): R = {
  allCatch.andFinally{t.close} apply { f(t) }
}

def read(f: File) =
  withCloseable(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(f))) { is =>
    Stream.continually(is.read()).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
  }
```

Now you could wrap it with `Try` and recover on some exceptions:

```
val result =
  Try { read(f) }.recover{
    case e: IOException => recover(e) // logging, default value
    case e: FileNotFoundException => recover(e)
  }
val array = result.get // Exception here!
```

Answer (score 2):

1. take ["scala-arm"](http://jsuereth.com/scala-arm/usage.html)
2. take [Apache "commons-io"](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

then do the following

```
val result = 
  for {fis <- resource.managed(new FileInputStream(f))
       gis <- resource.managed(new GZIPInputStream(fis))}
  yield IOUtils.toString(gis, "UTF-8")

result.acquireFor(identity) fold (reportExceptions _, v => v)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way how to handle it would be to use a mutable list of things that are opened and need to be closed later:

```
val cs: Buffer[Closeable] = new ArrayBuffer();
def addClose[C <: Closeable](c: C) = { cs += c; c; }

catching(classOf[IOException], classOf[FileNotFoundException]).
  andFinally({ cs.foreach(_.close()) }).
  either ({
      val is = addClose(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(f)))
      Stream.continually(is.read()).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
    }) // ...
```

---

**Update:** You could use [scala-conduit](https://github.com/ppetr/scala-conduit) library (I'm the author) for this purpose. (The library is currently not considered production ready.) The main aim of pipes (AKA conduids) is to construct composable components with well defined resource handling. Each pipe repeatedly receives input and  produces input. Optionally, it also produces a final result when it finishes. Pips has finalizers that are run after a pipe finishes - either on its own or when its downstream pipe finishes. Your example could be reworked (using Java NIO) as follows:

```
/**
 * Filters buffers until a given character is found. The last buffer
 * (truncated up to the character) is also included.
 */
def untilPipe(c: Byte): Pipe[ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer,Unit] = ...

// Create a new source that chunks a file as ByteBuffer's.
// (Note that the buffer changes on every step.)
val source: Source[ByteBuffer,Unit] = ...

// Sink that prints bytes to the standard output.
// You would create your own sink doing whatever you want.
val sink: Sink[ByteBuffer,Unit]
  = NIO.writeChannel(Channels.newChannel(System.out));

runPipe(source >-> untilPipe(-1) >-> sink);
```

As soon as `untilPipe(-1)` finds `-1` and finishes, its upstream `source` pipe's finalizer is run and the input is closed. If an exception occurs anywhere in the pipeline, the input is closed as well.

The full example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/ppetr/5831433).

Answer (score 0):

I have another one proposition for cases when a closeble object like java.io.Socket may run for a long time, so one have to wrap it in Future. This is handful when you also control a timeout, when Socket is not responding.

```
object CloseableFuture {
  type Closeable = {
    def close(): Unit
  }

  private def withClose[T, F1 <: Closeable](f: => F1, andThen: F1 => Future[T]): Future[T] = future(f).flatMap(closeable => {
    val internal = andThen(closeable)
    internal.onComplete(_ => closeable.close())
    internal
  })

  def apply[T, F1 <: Closeable](f: => F1, andThen: F1 => T): Future[T] =
    withClose(f, {c: F1 => future(andThen(c))})

  def apply[T, F1 <: Closeable, F2 <: Closeable](f1: => F1, thenF2: F1 => F2, andThen: (F1,F2) => T): Future [T] =
    withClose(f1, {c1:F1 => CloseableFuture(thenF2(c1), {c2:F2 => andThen(c1,c2)})})
}
```

After I open a java.io.Socket and java.io.InputStream for it, and then execute code which reads from WhoisServer, I got both of them closed finally. Full code:

```
CloseableFuture(
      {new Socket(server.address, WhoisPort)},
      (s: Socket) => s.getInputStream,
      (socket: Socket, inputStream: InputStream) => {
        val streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream)
        val bufferReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader)
        val outputStream = socket.getOutputStream
        val writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)
        val bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer)
        bufferWriter.write(urlToAsk+System.getProperty("line.separator"))
        bufferWriter.flush()
        def readBuffer(acc: List[String]): List[String] = bufferReader.readLine() match {
          case null => acc
          case str => {
            readBuffer(str :: acc)
          }
        }
        val result = readBuffer(Nil).reverse.mkString("\r\n")
        WhoisResult(urlToAsk, result)
      }
    )
```